# Flutter Run not working, Error launching application on iPhone

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have updated the flutter version recently. after that flutter run is not working on iPhone. I am using android studio. run button on the android studio also not working for iPhone but simulators are working fine.

I am getting the following error. I have set the runner schema to release. still no luck.

> "Error launching application on Raj iPhone."

[image]

Flutter version.

> Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.374, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2
> darwin-x64, locale en-GB)

I am not getting any additional errors. so i run flutter run -verbose i got the following info

> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:618:7)
>
> #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1119:12)
>
> #3      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:974:27)
>
> #4      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
>
> #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:264:9)
>
> #8      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
>
> #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:220:5)
>
> #11     run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:9)
>
> #12     run. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:12)
>
> #13     AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
>
> #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:70:10)
>
> #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
>
> ```
>         [ +113 ms] (lldb) process detach [ +254 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 255ms [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks [
> ```
>
> ] Shutdown hook priority 4 [  +52 ms] Shutdown hooks complete [
> ] exiting with code 1

I have done flutter clean and checked again. still same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you opened the project through xcode and registered your iphone?
Try to compile at least once directly from xcode to the iphone.

Comment: until i upgrade the flutter. it was working fine. my iphone id was added to the developer profile. its not the first time i run this project. i was working on it for a month. after the upgrade it stops working

Comment: now, i tried to run from xcode workspace. its running fine. only issue is flutter run on device failed :(

Answer (score 5):

In `flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart`, find the following code block:

```
_logger.printTrace('Application launched on the device. Waiting for observatory port.');
Uri localUri;
try {
  localUri = await observatoryDiscovery.uri.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
} on TimeoutException {
  await observatoryDiscovery.cancel();
}
```

Increase the timeout to a bigger number, for example, 60 seconds fixed it for me:

```
localUri = await observatoryDiscovery.uri.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 60));
```

[image]

Also, remove the cached binaries to force snapshot regeneration:

```
rm /{$PATH_TO_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY}/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp /{$PATH_TO_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY}/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot
```

References:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/a603714610f8c9c831e7d85071274460d70c18da/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart#L432
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools#forcing-snapshot-regeneration

Comment: In addition to this, you'll also need to force snapshot regeneration of `flutter_tools`, otherwise the changes you make to the dart code won't be applied. To do this you can run `rm /{$PATH_TO_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY}/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp /{$PATH_TO_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY}/bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot`. Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools#forcing-snapshot-regeneration

Comment: Thanks @brianbhsu - I added your helpful comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

###### Delete or Clear directory `~/Library/Develope/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/` is not recommended.

In my case, that is the flutter sdk bundled command `ios-deploy` (version  `1.11.2-beta.1`) issue. It find the wrong path of `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/[iOS_Version_ARCH]/Symbols`.

1. First check your `ios-deploy` version:
   `__PATH_TO_YOUR_Flutter_SDK_/bin/cache/artifacts/ios-deploy/ios-deploy --version`
2. Replace it with to current newest version `1.12.1`.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy.git
   cd ios-deploy/ 
   git checkout 1.12.1

   ## build it 
   xcodebuild -project ios-deploy.xcodeproj -list
   xcodebuild -project ios-deploy.xcodeproj -scheme ios-deploy

   ## get the built output path
   xcodebuild -project ios-deploy.xcodeproj -scheme ios-deploy -showBuildSettings | grep BUILD_DIR  

   ## or use Xcode to build
   open ios-deploy.xcodeproj  ## Build project with key: ⌘ + B

   ## check the output file
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-[xxxxx]/Build/Products/Debug/ios-deploy  --version 

   ## replace the one in flutter sdk
   cp ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-deploy-[xxxxx]/Build/Products/Debug/ios-deploy __PATH_TO_YOUR_Flutter_SDK_/bin/cache/artifacts/ios-deploy/
   ```
3. Run your flutter project again with `Android studio` or `Visual Studio Code` or `flutter run` again. Finally succeeded.