# Got the "Error launching application on" after flutter run

Tags: flutter

I am flowing the official [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) to install flutter and run the default app on my iPhone Device. After I execute the `flutter run`, the app is installed and launched on my iPhone but the logs show the bellow error. How do I solve it?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on My iPhone 6 in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: XXXXXXXXXX
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking, and signing...                        50.2s
Xcode builds done.                                           90.1s
Installing and launching...                                        41.1s
Error launching the application on My iPhone 6. <-- Error Here
```

Comment: did you try to open, compile and run the project from Xcode at least once ?

Comment: @glavigno yes, I had tried to run it from Xcode once but still got the error after flutter run.

Comment: Try to run the project from xcode so you can get accurate error

Comment: @Priyesh The app do not get any errors after run it from Xcode.

Comment: now again run from android studio after xcode

Comment: @Priyesh There are also no errors from Android Studio.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on my iPhone 5, strangely it actually installs the app, but can't launch it.

Comment: Has anyone managed to resolve this yet? Seeing it on my 12 mini

Comment: @joelgate I just had the same issue on my  iPhone 11. I had to start xcode and then it works fine with logs in terminal until the phone locks the screen.

Comment: I´m also facing this issue

Comment: Any update on this to resolve it?

Answer (score 21):

It happens that there are some process needed to Flutter plugin correctly run on physical devices. I struggled with that and finally found that the processes `idevicesyslog` and `iproxy` were being silently blocked by MacOS.
You may have noticed already a message liked this:

[image: Mac suggesting to remove iproxy]

or a similar one for idevicesyslog.

Once I went to System Settings -> Security & Privacy in General tab and allowed this apps, everything works. Note that this screen shows only the last app that you tried to run. So I'd recommend that you run flutter app with preferences opened so you can (hopefully) see the messages appearing and click allow.

[image: Option to allow the app. Here it should show one of those 2 names above at a time]

MacOS may warn you one more time about the file being downloaded from the internet. Just click open and you're good.

Comment: There is no Allow button in General Tab although I get this error

Comment: For now it seems, I could not understand it was not seen but now it seen. So the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: I really wish that you stated which System Preferences you are talking about :( Mac has system settings not preferences I don't think you meant it!.. still searching

Comment: Okays in new MacOS, just go SystemSettings, then Privacy and Security, scroll down and below security label, you will see a similar prompt that this was blocked, and the allow button. I tried it and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: You're right @AKhudairy. I fixed the name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error do not show again after reboot the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Same error -- Running fine through Xcode, when I ran with flutter CLI, the app would open, but the terminal log output would crash with the error as in the post.

I ran `flutter update` and simultaneously turned iPhone off and back on. After doing that, the below popup appeared (on mac).

[image: A software update is required to connect to iPhone]

I believe after the install finished, I ran the below (which I ran several times before updating flutter and installing the popup):

```sh
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Pods
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

run the flutter app using flutter run from command line, then the MacBook will ask for permission to open the app and app runs,

Answer (score 0):

1. (lldb) warning: libobjc.A.dylib is being read from process memory. This indicates that LLDB could not find the on-disk shared cache for this device. This will likely reduce debugging performance.
2. Error launching application on device-XXXXX.

Building & Replace with a newest version `ios-deploy` solved problems list aboved. Flutter SDK bundled a pre-built command `ios-deploy` in `__PATH_TO_YOUR_Flutter_SDK_/bin/cache/artifacts/ios-deploy/`, just replace it.
Please reference to: [Flutter Error launching application on device issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75479628/1749293) .